# response time of the PCI-6602 Counter/Timer module

Tags: hardware, labview

I am using a NI PCI-6602 Counter/Timer to send TTL signals to another device in our lab. I have to send the signal every ~ 3 - 5 ms, but this time is not fixed (it depends on some other processes I am doing in my LabVIEW program), so I cannot work with a continuous waveform.

Therefore, I have written a short test program to get familiar with the PCI-6602 ([see vi](http://forums.ni.com/ni/attachments/ni/40/10027/1/ExampleResponseTime.vi)) and to see how I can generate a single pulse.

If I generate a single pulse, it seems that I can do this only about all 14 ms (at least this is the time difference calculated with tick counts which is not very precise; but counting the pulses with a counter gives almost the same time). So it seems that the PCI-6602 has a too long response time for my application!

Can somebody tell me if she/he makes the same observation? Or am I using the wrong vi/treating the PCI-6602 in the wrong way? If yes, what do I have to do to make my little test program and finally my main program faster?
I would appreciate every help and comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the great support of Dan of the LabVIEW forum it was possible to solve this problem by using a nice workaround.
[Here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Counter-Timer/PCI-6602-response-time/m-p/1811280) is the link to the discussion and the working VI in case somebody is interested in the details.